# Spacing in complicated equations

Tags: spacing

I have some longer term where some of the factors have a functional dependence in parentheses. When I just write this out, the parentheses are closer to the next symbol than to the symbol that they actually belong to.

My code:

```
\bar v^{s'}(\tens p_2) \mat\gamma^\mu u^s(\tens p_1)
\bar u^r(\tens k_1) \mat\gamma^\nu v^{r'}(\tens k_2)
\bar v^{s'}(\tens p_2) \mat\gamma^\rho u^s(\tens p_1)
\bar u^r(\tens k_1) \mat\gamma^\lambda v^{r'}(\tens k_2).
```

The font options are the following:

```
\RequirePackage[charter, greekuppercase=italicized]{mathdesign}
\RequirePackage{beramono}
\RequirePackage{berasans}

\RequirePackage{isomath}
\renewcommand{\vec}{\vectorsym}
\newcommand{\tens}{\tensorsym}
\newcommand{\mat}{\matrixsym}
```

The output:

[image: Output of the previous LaTeX code]

Would it make sense to add a lot of `\,` between the individual terms? Is there some general rule which would give me some guidance?

Comment: What are the definitions of `\tens` and `\mat`? What fonts are you using?

Comment: The fonts are Charter and Bera Sans. The `\tens` and `\mat` are defined with the `isomath` package. I added it to my question.

Comment: The spacing provided by the `mathdesign` version of Charter in math mode is quite tight. In particular the gamma should have a wider left sidebearing (and the u as well). In cases like these, it makes sense to add `\,` after the closing parentheses.